# MySQL, REPLACE INTO without deleting?

Tags: mysql

I have this table structure:

```
ID RATE1 RATE2 RATE3
```

and its empty. Lets give a new rate:

```
REPLACE INTO rates (ID, RATE2) VALUES (99, 4);
```

the table will be:

```
99, 0, 4, 0
```

so far so good. Another rating takes place:

```
REPLACE INTO rates (ID, RATE3) VALUES (99, 2);
```

and this is where the error happens. I get

```
99, 0, 0, 2
```

instead of:

```
99, 0, 4, 2
```

I wanted to retain RATE2 too. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` instead of `REPLACE`.

```
INSERT INTO ThisTable (id, rate3) VALUES (99, 2) 
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE rate3=VALUES(rate3);
```

This leaves the other columns of an existing row as they were.

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ae4a

Comment: if I want to generalize it: after the following: ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, I always have to copy the "rate3=VALUES(rate3)" expression according to the columns that Im updating?

Comment: Yes, this updates the specified columns with the values you tried to insert. You might want to read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html for more information.